# Как в С++ поместить массив в кэш-память процессора?

Tags: c++, кэширование, производительность

Есть ли в С++ какие-либо средства, позволяющие при выполнении программы размещать созданный константный массив в кэш-память 1 уровня? Может хотя бы рекомендацию такую можно дать, типа рекомендации `register` для переменной.

Comment: Нет. Язык ничего не знает о машине, процессоре и так далее. И вообще - вы точно знаете, что именно это является узким местом в вашей программе?

Comment: Если вы выполнили какую-либо операцию с данными массива, например, посчитали сумму, то некоторое время массив будет находится в кеше, пока не будет вытеснен более актуальными данными.

Comment: @Harry Насчет узкого места - не знаю, хотелось проверить бы) Это как один из вариантов поднять производительность.

Comment: *"Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол" (с) Д.Э.Кнут* Как часто приходится встречать вопросы типа "как ускорить вызов вот этой функции, каким ассемблером", или "как распараллелить программу, чтоб ускорить", когда изменение алгоритма ведет к изменению O(n^2) к какому-нибудь O(log n)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Язык сам по себе ничего подобного не предусматривает, однако большинство современных компиляторов предоставляют наборы встраиваемых функций с различными платформо-специфичными функциями.

На x86 для подобных целей есть функции *_prefetch, например загрузка кеш линии в кеш первого уровня из адреса:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
int main()
{
   int val{};
   _mm_prefetch(&val, 1);
}
```

Но на практике более интересны функции *_stream, позволяющие подгружать и выгружать данные избегая обычного алгоритма кеширования.

Comment: cache_level must be a const